# Add a number for each data-toggle="modal" and data-target="exampleModal" in a generated HTML code

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop

I have some mapped json data to display the results in a container. Each list from the generated html must open a separate modal window. To do this, I need to associate a number to each `data-toggle="modal"` and to each `data-target="exampleModal"` in the generated code.

I tried to add in `data-modal="modal${res[i]}` but I don't get a number this way.

The generated code:

```
const res = some.d.results; //arr of objects
let ul = document.querySelector('#test');
            const html = res.map(el=> {
                for (i = 1; i < res.length; i++) {
                    return `<li class="box-top box-top--feat" type="button" data-toggle="modal${res[i]}" data-target="exampleModal${res[i]}">
                                <a class="box-top__content" href="#">
                                    <div class="box-top__title__img2">
                                        <img class="availableImgs" alt="" src="${res.dirRef}${'/'}${res.fileRef}" />
                                    </div>
                                        <h2 class="box-top__title">${res.PersonA.Person}</h2>
                                        <h3 class="box-top__work">${res.Title}</h3>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal${res[i]}" tabindex="-1">
                                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <p>${res.DescA.PersA]}</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>`;
                }
            }).join("");
```

What is the proper way to add a number here?

Comment: You seem to be looping over `res` multiple times, once with `map()` and once with `for(...)`. But then your for-loop is returning on the first iteration and therefore not reaching subsequent iterations. You can include an index in your `map()`: `res.map((el,i) => {...}`.

Comment: @user1599011 I succeeded and solved the issue thanks to your answer. Thank you!

Comment: I'm going to add this as an answer, for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looping over res multiple times, once with map() and once with for(...). But then your for-loop is returning on the first iteration and therefore not reaching subsequent iterations.
You can include an index in your map(): res.map((el,i) => {...} and then use that instance of `i`, rather than a separate for-loop.